# Number of rectangles on a checkerboard with at least 4 black squares

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

How many distinct rectangles , with sides on the grid lines of the checkerboard and containing at least 4 black squares , can be drawn on the checkerboard ?

I tried to solve the problem by counting all the possible rectangles on a 8x8 board and then taking away all the rectangles with less than 4 squares but this type of counting took me a lot of cases to deal with (1x1 , 1x2 , 1x3 , 2x3 , ecc...).

My question is : Is there a more clever way to solve this problem , without summing or subtracting many cases?

[image]

Comment: Is this a HW question?

Comment: Are you able to answer the much simpler question of how many rectangles there are where you don't care how many black squares are used?  Now, how about the only slightly harder question of how many there are with *fewer* than $4$ black squares used?

Comment: I edited my question. I think that i used your reasoning but it took me lot of cases to deal with. Is there a better method?

Comment: Yes I counted them by hand :D . Now I try to think about a formula. Is a summation related to the size of rectangles , isn't it?

Comment: Combinations I would say. For example, to count the number of 1x3 rectangles (i.e. 3 adjacent squares in the same row), all you need to do is realize that there are 8 rows, and for each row, there are 6 ways to get 3 adjacent ones. So: 8*6=48 rectangles of that kind. Etc.

Comment: "*Yes I counted them by hand*"  That is almost never a good idea.  The whole point of an introductory course in combinatorics is to get you out of the habit of doing that and showing you tools that you can use to do things more efficiently.

Comment: No I'm sorry I'm not very good at english , i misundertood the question. I counted with counting methods but i wasn't really satisfied with my counting

Comment: As for counting *all* possible rectangles: see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of rectangles $n\times m$ in the board is $2(9-n)(9-m)$ if $m$ and $n$ are different and $(9-n)^2$ otherwise.

The rectangles that **do not** have four black squares are 1x1, 1x2, ..., 1x6, 2x2 and 2x3, and the half of 1x7.

This makes
$$8^2+2\cdot 7\cdot 8+2\cdot 6\cdot 8+\cdots 2\cdot 3\cdot 8+2\cdot 8+7^2+2\cdot 6\cdot 5$$
$$=64+2\cdot8\sum_{k=3}^7k+16+49+60$$
$$=64+25\cdot16+16+49+60=589$$

The total number of rectangles in the board is given by 
$$\sum_{k=1}^8(9-k)^2+2\sum_{j=1}^7\sum_{k=j+1}^8(9-j)(9-k)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^8k\right)^2=1296$$

Comment: I think that you overcounted a case : 1x7 rectangles , because one of the two possible for each row or column has 4 black squares

Comment: I realized that before reading your comment. Fixed.

Comment: How did you come with the equality which passes from the two summations to just one squared ?

Comment: Remember the identity $(a_1+a_2+\cdots a_k)^2=a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_k^2+2\cdot[\text{the sum of all possible products of different $a_j$'s}]$

Comment: woow I didn't recognized it !!

Comment: Shouldn't it be 2*6*7 for 2x3 rectangles?

Answer (score 2):

To quickly count the number of rectangles of *any* size: Note that any rectangle is uniquely defined by a left and a right horizontal grid line, and a left and right vertical gridline. There are 9 horizontal gridlines, so you need to choose 2 different ones out of those: $9 \choose 2$. Likewise, there are $9 \choose 2$ possible pairs of vertical gridlines. So, you have ${9 \choose 2} \times {9 \choose 2}$ possible rectangles total: $36 \times 36 = 1296$